# Error in plotting a quantity involving integral!

Tags: plotting, matrix, numerical-integration

With my limited knowledge of Mathematica, I tried  but could not figure out the issues in the following few-line code:

```
   mat1 = 1/2 ( {
     {1, -I},
     {I, 1}
    } );
mat2[x_, t_] = {{1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] - Sqrt[
     1 - 4 x^2]/(-1 + E^(t Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2])), I x}, {-I x, 
    1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2] + (
       2 Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2])/(-1 + E^(t Sqrt[1 - 4 x^2])))}};

intx = Integrate[mat2[x, t], {t, 0, 50}];
int0 = Integrate[mat2[0, t], {t, 0, 50}];
quantity[x_] := (Tr[ mat1.intx] - Tr[mat1.int0] )^2;

Plot[quantity[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Integral  does not converge ?

Comment: To add to @Mariusz: Order-1 pole at t=0: `Series[mat2[x, t], {t, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the lower bound of the integrals. Starting from zero would set the denominators equal to zero and consequently the integrals would not converge. Try to set the lower bound to `0 + ϵ`.

```
intx = Integrate[mat2[x, t], {t, 0.01, 50}];
int0 = Integrate[mat2[0, t], {t, 0.01, 50}];
```